# Copying large amount of data between volumes on Windows 2008, fast method?

Tags: windows-server-2008, robocopy, copying

I need to copy data from/to very large volumes (2TB) on a Windows 2008 Server. Are there any tools I should consider using that maximizes throughput (hopefully with a resume-function)?

I've always used copy/paste, wich have worked fine when I don't need resume - but this copy operation probably needs some pausing at intervals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally really like robocopy. In Server 2008 they added multi-threaded copy to it.

http://blogs.msdn.com/granth/archive/2009/12/07/multi-threaded-robocopy-for-faster-copies.aspx

Ross

Answer (score 0):

I would try TeraCopy: http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php

Answer (score 0):

If the source data may change during transfer (ex. live file server) I would consider DFSR. If not, simply use xxcopy. Read the documentation carefully because there are LOTS of parameters to turn on and off depending on your needs (preserve ACLs, timestamps, enable pause function, etc.)